# What standards must US ISPs currently uphold in the quality of their speed and ping?

Tags: united-states, internet, civil-law, consumer-protection, advertisements

I'm curious. After a generous amount of googling, I couldn't find any laws or codes from the FCC regarding the standards of quality regarding internet speed and access.

What laws are currently in place which set the standards for advertised speeds of internet verses actual speeds and where can I read about them? If there are no laws, what keeps my internet provider from advertising 1,000,000 Mb/s and giving me 10 Mb/s?

Comment: There are laws against false advertising.  Somewhere in the fine print of your ISP's sales material there's almost certainly a disclaimer that says it's the max speed the hardware will deliver under perfect conditions, actual speed will vary with network load &c.  (Also, it's not actually that easy to determine whether slow access is due to network speed, or slow servers on the web sites you access.)

Comment: @Panda thought law se was about legislation process,  not about law specifics?

Comment: @tuskiomi Not really, legislation process is only on-topic on this site, Politics.SE. From [Help Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *"Processes are central to legislation is made. Questions seeking to understand the rules and processes by which policy is made in various legislatures or ruling bodies (inside and outside of the United States!) are wholly on topic".* Law questions in general are more suited on Law.SE.

Comment: @tuskiomi Actually it's the other way around. Politics.SE is about how and why laws are made, Law.SE is about what laws there are and how they are applied in the real world. I will migrate it.